# CSS Reposition/overwrite a class

Tags: css

I have zero knowledge on CCS so i dont actually know how to call the elements.

Im going to try to explain myself the best i could do.

Im using a class called "sign"

```
<div class="sign">

    .sign { 
        background-image: url(/images/background.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        left: 18px;
        top: -37px;
        margin-top: 38px;
        margin-bottom: -23px;
        padding: 15px;
        height: 202px;
        width: 154px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
    }
```

My existential doubt is... what should i do to reposition "sign"?

As a first though, this is what came to my mind but dont know if its even possible

```
.sign-repos { 
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: 36px;
    top: -55px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-bottom: -11px;
}

<div class="sign" class2="sign-repos">
```

**Solution:**

```
<div class="sign sign-repos">
```

Comment: Well, `class2` isn't valid so you can forget that. To override the CSS from `.sign` you can either make a [more specific selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), or write another `.sign` selector and have it loaded after the one you don't want.

Comment: Like @j08691 said - override it https://jsfiddle.net/tnry4cg2/

Comment: Are you repositioning it temporarily or permanently?

Comment: @David solution was so simple, thanks alot! > Nathaniel Flick permanently since its on a different subpage

Comment: If they are on different pages (or "sub"pages?) you might want to use two classes from the start... `<div class="sign position-one">` and `<div class="sign position-two">` so the stuff like background-image, padding, height that remains consistent is part of the `.sign { ... }` CSS, then the stuff about left, top, etc. is part of the `.position_xyz { ... }` CSS classes.

Comment: @StephenP perfectly understood, thanks for the advice